# :-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status. Can anyone please tell why this error?

Tags: c++, qt

Can anyone please tell why this error? I have included everything ( all header, sources and form class) in my .pro file

Error message:

> debug/moc_calculatorform.o:moc_calculatorform.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14CalculatorForm[v‌​table for CalculatorForm]+0xb0):
>
> undefined reference to `CalculatorForm::changeEvent(QEvent*)'
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit
> status mingw32-make.exe[1]:
>
> [debug\calculatorform.exe] Error 1
> mingw32-make.exe:
> [debug] Error 2 13:02:27: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2. Error while building project calculatorform (target: Qt Simulator) When executing build step 'Make'

Comment: Did it give you anymore information?  Currently we know failed, that's it.

Comment: no nothing except what i have writtne

Comment: debug/moc_calculatorform.o:moc_calculatorform.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV14CalculatorForm[vtable for CalculatorForm]+0xb0): undefined reference to `CalculatorForm::changeEvent(QEvent*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug\calculatorform.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
13:02:27: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project calculatorform (target: Qt Simulator)
When executing build step 'Make'

Comment: I know why this error. Line number 0x007 causes this error.

Comment: @Nawaz I think you mean 0x006 *obviously*

Comment: and what is Line number 0x007 and how to solve it?

Comment: @Raven - They are just kidding. You don't tell us enough to see where the problem is. So one guess is that could be on line 7, or line 6, or any other line. We just don't know.

Comment: @Default: Actually, that is pretty much obvious. If the error is at line number 0x007, then to fix it, you may have to look all the lines from `0x000` to `0x007` which includes `0x006` by Default.;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`undefined reference to CalculatorForm::changeEvent(QEvent*)`

There's your answer, the linker can't find the definition of this method - you have probably forgotten to implement it.

Comment: no. i have implemented that too

Comment: It's coming from Qt's `moc` output though, have you done a clean rebuild since implementing it?

Comment: ok. yeah i missed that in one file. Thankx :)

Comment: but now it says  error: cannot call member function 'virtual void QWidget::changeEvent(QEvent*)' without object

Comment: How are you calling it from where that error is produced?